# First import of python modules slow on a new VM, even after warming __pycache__?

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.7, cpython

I have an Amazon Linux image that I use for some ML tasks, which use Python heavily. When I spin up a new machine, the first time I import all the python packages (numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, xarray, etc.) take a long time-- if I import absolutely everything, it's about 80 seconds. Subsequent imports, even in separate Python processes on the same VM, are extremely fast: 1-2 seconds for everything.

I'd like to eliminate that minute-plus on startup if I could; I only pay the performance cost once per VM, but the VMs are short-lived (typically for one job, perhaps 45-60 minutes).

My original assumption was that this was related to `__pycache__`; that the minute the first time was compiling and caching the bytecode of all the libraries, and the subsequent runs were faster because all that was already finished. So I added a script to my image builder, that imported every single module I ever reference as part of creating the image. However, the results were not all as I expected, and there was no performance gain:

1. Running the script as part of the image builder is almost instant (I was not expecting this).
2. Running the script does create the expected `__pycache__` files alongside their sources in site-packages.
3. The `__pycache__` files exist on systems created from the image, before any python has ever been run.
4. Running the script on a system newly created from the image still takes over a minute, even though the `__pycache__` files are already in place.
5. Running the script on the same system a second time takes under a second.
6. `<module>.__cached__` on the system created from the image appears to refer to the correct .pyc file in the correct `__pycache__` folder that was in place from the image.
7. The dates of all the .pyc files in the `__pycache__` folders reflect the time of image creation, not of VM instantiation.

So it seems that while my "import everything" script *does* result in creating `__pycache__` files, it doesn't actually have any impact at all on the startup time on a system created from an image with those files. Is there something else that is persisted across python sessions on the same machine other than the .pyc files? Is there a different cache of .pyc files other than that stored in site-packages that might be being checked?

Comment: "`numpy`, `scipy`, `scikit-learn`, `xarray`, etc." is hundreds of megabytes, if not gigabytes, worth of files to load. Mostly C extensions, not Python modules where `__pycache__` matters. If the VM is lazily loading the backing file system over the network, that could easily take a *while* to pull into the local host's cache and load. If you only run once, then revert to the base state each time, `__pycache__` isn't doing you any good anyway, you might try running with `-B` (or setting `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` in the environment) to *prevent* writing bytecode files.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The idea was that I'm storing the files (including pycache, compiled C, etc.) in an AMI (Amazon Machine Image), and then on VM startup I'm creating an EBS volume from the image, which is then run on the workers. My impression was that's eager rather than lazy, I guess I was figuring that it was as simple as creating a slightly larger .vhd file, but my cloud knowledge is mixed. Alternatives would be 1) pip installing all the packages on the workers upon startup, or b) pip installing on the image, but without using pycache,

Comment: @ShadowRanger My goal here (which may be impossible) is that the first load of python files on a new VM would be as fast the second load on the same VM. Since the performance gain is persistent across python instances, I figured there must be some way that the state is persistent on disk, but it seems I may be missing something (perhaps that the VM is RAM caching the files loaded from disk-- not sure if that was what you meant by cache?)

Comment: Yeah, the VM performing RAM caching is where a slowdown could easily be an issue. Even if the VM is provisioned eagerly (no network latency to read from disk once VM running), loading a GB of cold files from the disk could easily take several seconds (depends on how much contention there is for local disk resources, whether its spinning or solid state, etc.). 80 seconds seems long for anything local though, thus speculating that the VM might launch without having eagerly pulled the entire image locally (causing the initial load to pay cost of pulling from network, not just disk).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I followed up with AWS. EBS initialization from an AMI IS lazy by default, as suggested in your first comment. Once initialized the EBS volume is fast after a reboot, but unfortunately that would defeat the entire point here.